# Can't access getcomposer.org in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl, composer-php

I can't access https://getcomposer.org (through URL and Curl). When I tried to access through URL it's not loading the page. And when I curl the same it shows Connection Timed Out.

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to getcomposer.org port 443: Connection
> timed out

I need to install Composer in my Ubuntu.

`sudo apt-get install composer`

This worked fine for me. But when I tried to self update using

`sudo composer self-update`

it throws an error.

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
> Command "self-update" is not defined.

I have already tried different solutions in Stack Overflow and GitHub. But nothing work for me. I didn't enabled any firewall and not using any proxy. OpenSSL is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to access https://getcomposer.org with VPN from [vpnbook](https://www.vpnbook.com/)
and it works fine. For some people getcomposer.org will not accessible, because their Lan may be shared with multiple people. So if you can't access getcomposer.org, have a try with any VPN.